# Execute rest call in synchronous way using httpclient

Tags: java, rest, httpclient

I've to execute two rest calls one after the another.

```
//first rest call
httpClient.execute(.....)
//second rest call, should only execute after successful completion of the 
//first restcall
httpClient.execute(.....)
```

The second rest call should only proceed after the first rest call succeeds.

Is there a way I can achieve that using HttpClient?

Comment: You can simply start the second after the first one finish (callback) doing sync on main thread is not recommended, doing both sequentially on the same thread is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to put the second call in first response handler, example:

```
 try {
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://httpbin.org/");
        HttpGet httpget1 = new HttpGet("http://httpbin.org/");

        System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine());

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new ResponseHandler<String>() {

            @Override
            public String handleResponse(
                    final HttpResponse response) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (status >= 200 && status < 300) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    if(entity != null){
                       httpclient.execute(httpget1, responseHandler1);
                    }else{
                       return "No response";
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new ClientProtocolException("Unexpected response status: " + status);
                }
            }

        };

        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler1 = new ResponseHandler<String>() {

            @Override
            public String handleResponse(
                    final HttpResponse response) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
                int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                if (status >= 200 && status < 300) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                    return entity != null ? EntityUtils.toString(entity) : null;
                } else {
                    throw new ClientProtocolException("Unexpected response status: " + status);
                }
            }

        };
        String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(responseBody);
    } finally {
        httpclient.close();
    }
```

Comment: No problem, my pleasure :)